# objective-c - Doesn't upload file's content

Tags: iphone, objective-c, upload

I want to upload a local word (or rtf) file to my server. Uploads the file without content. There is no error code or anything..

```
NSString *urlString = @"http://myserver.com/upload-c.php";
NSString *filename=@"xx.docx";

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"xx.docx"]];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init] autorelease];
[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
[request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];

NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n",filename]] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];

[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[request setHTTPBody:body];

NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
NSString *returnString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

NSLog(@"%@",returnString);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is with how you initialize your `data` variable.

Assuming "xx.docx" is the file you wish to upload, you have two problems.

1. You need to specify the full path to the file, not just the filename.
2. Since you are creating an `NSURL` from a file path, you need to use `fileURLWithPath:`, not `URLWithString:`.

Edit: Based on your comments, the file is located in the app's resource bundle. To get its fullpath you should do this:

```
NSString *fullPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"xx" ofType:@"docx"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:fullPath];
```

Also, this line:

```
[body appendData:[NSData dataWithData:data]];
```

should simply be:

```
[body appendData:data];
```

And get rid of the calls to `stringWithString:`. Example:

```
[body appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

should be:

```
[body appendData:[@"Content-Type: application/octet-stream\r\n\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

and:

```
NSString *boundary = [NSString stringWithString:@"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449"];
```

should be:

```
NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
```

Comment: "You need to specify the full path to the file, not just the filename." it is the same directory with .h and .m files? it is not in a subdirectory?

Comment: You need to deal with the runtime environment of your app here, not the project. At runtime, the file is sitting at some specific path on the user's device. You need to determine that full path to the file.

Comment: Where is the file? Is it in your app's resource bundle or was is saved in the "Documents" folder (or some other folder in the app's sandbox)?

Comment: How can I find the fullpath of the file in runtime? Is there a way to find it?

Comment: It is in my project folder. Where I should locate it?

Comment: Actually I want to put it in my resource bundle